# CSS margin-top and top are not bound

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having some trouble with a page that has a floating background image (absolutely positioned) where the image is dynamically changed out via javascript. Basically this is a big gallery that changes behind a portfolio:

I have a section of markup that looks like this:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="content-image">
      <img id="galleryTarget" src="../images/main/source.jpg" class="image-resize" alt="background image"/>
    </div> 
    ...etc...
```

Here's the relevant CSS classes:

```
.image-resize {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 750px;
    min-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: -25%;
    top: 25%;
}

.content-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 750px;
    max-height: 750px;
    min-width:1000px;
    overflow:visible;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 1;
}

.content-container {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 750px;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 750px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: purple;
    z-index: -5;    
}
```

This is all absolutely positioned so that I can swap out the image source with Javascript and then dynamically resize the container (background) to fill the new content. There's minimum bounds so it always has a size.

What I'm trying to do is to pin this image to a CENTER point so that when it is resized the interesting parts of the image (rarely the top left corner) are displayed.

In the inspector in chrome I see that `top` and `margin-top` are never the same value even though they have the same (percentage) value. What am I missing here?

Example:
  `top: 187.5px` and margin-top: `-389.5px`. It looks as though margin-top uses the img-source resolution and `top` uses something for the life of me I can't figure out--I'm assuming min-height + the offset in the page?

Any help here would be appreciated, this is a rather large part of the design and I'd love to have it better than what it is.

Browsers: 
Chrome Version: 30.0.1599.66 m
Android Chrome: 30.0.1599.82

Comment: looks like top is half of margin... use calc() instead of abspos if you only need chrome support.

Comment: This will eventually be cross-browser, this is just the initial spec (chrome is faster to debug in my experience)

Comment: still, you can do the same thing in IE and FF as well. old IE uses a slightly different expression syntax, but it too can spec the values you need in CSS.

Comment: I can set a manual offset to this, but is there a way to reference another value as the start point for the calculation? This could, potentially, solve the problem if I could bind the margin attribute to the top attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This does fix the problem in chrome--but I'd like to know why it is using 1000px as the baseline for the margin instead of the 750px of the unit.

```
/*Hack of a vector similar to 50%*/
margin-top: calc(-50% * 0.75);
top: 50%;
```